# Where should i add print on while true loop and how do i print all added text?

Tags: python

i need to do program that asks the user to enter words. When the user enters the "end", the program prints a story made up of words and execution ends without adding word "end"

Output should be like.

```
word: Small
word: blue
word: ship
word: end
Small blue ship
```

```
while True:
word = input("word:")
if word == "end":
    break
```

edit: thank you all for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code:

```
word = ""
while True:
   a = input("word: ")
   if a.lower() == "end":
      print(word)
      break
   else:
      word += a+' '
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store all the words in a list:

```
words = list()

while True:
    word = input('word:')
    if word != 'end':
        words.append(word)
    else:
        break

print(' '.join(words))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a list in this case makes it easier:

```
words = []

while(True):
    word = input('word: ')
    if (word == 'end'):
        break
    else:
        words.append(word)

for word in words:
    print(word, end=' ')
```